# Delete all the document older than a date using _id in mongo using mgo

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I'm working in `Golang` and `mgo` and I would like to delete all the documents in a collection older than a specified date, using `_id` value.

So far I've tried to create a dummy objectId using a struct `NewObjectIdWithTime` after that I'm trying to delete documents using

```
collection.Remove(bson.M{"_id": bson.M{"$lt": objectId}})
```

But I'm not getting any results, any suggestion?

Comment: why someone should downvote a question like this?

Comment: I agree. This question is useful, albeit it could be improved.

Comment: I've noticed a lot of strange downvotes around MongoDB questions. I think some people here don't like MongoDB...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I really don't like answer my self but since the only help I recive from stackoverflow community was a negative rating (without any explain) I post the solution:

The problem is mgo have [RemoveAll](https://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo#Collection.RemoveAll) where delete all the element match the criteria, so my new query is:`collection.RemoveAll(bson.M{"_id": bson.M{"$lt": objectId}})`